# Firebase Query some fields is null

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my structure screen shot:

[image: 1]

And the following is my Query:

```
databaseReference.child("user-events").child(Utility.getUserId())
```

I can get most of my data except startdate and starttime. The query result is null.

Would you please help me out? Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's not a valid query as well, there is no *query* and there is no child of user-events called Utility.getUserId()

Comment: This method from my Utility class.   public static String getUserId(){
        return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    }  I get that node and get most of my data(author, categlory, description, location, photoUrl, title and uid) but startdate, enddate, starttime & endtime except.

Comment: Sorry I didn't describe more detail.

Comment: There's not enough info to answer the question. Please post your code and review [How To Ask A Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)